# KeyError with Youtube API using python

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-data-api, keyerror

This is my first time to ask something here. I've been trying to access the Youtube API to get something for an experiment I'm doing. Everything's working so far. I just wanted to ask about this very inconsistent error that I'm getting.

```
-----------
1
Title:  All Movie Trailers of New York Comic-Con (2016) Power Rangers, John Wick 2...
Uploaded by:    KinoCheck International
Uploaded on:    2016-10-12T14:43:42.000Z
Video ID:   pWOH-OZQUj0
2
Title:  Movieclips Trailers
Uploaded by:    Movieclips Trailers
Uploaded on:    2011-04-01T18:43:14.000Z
Video ID:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapeyoutube.py", line 24, in <module>
    print "Video ID:\t", search_result['id']['videoId']
KeyError: 'videoId'
```

I tried getting the video ID ('videoID' as per documentation). But for some reason, the code works for the 1st query, and then totally flops for the 2nd one. It's weird because it's only happening for this particular element. Everything else ('description','publishedAt', etc.) is working. Here's my code:

```
    from apiclient.discovery import build
import json
import pprint
import sys

APINAME = 'youtube'
APIVERSION = 'v3'
APIKEY = 'secret teehee'

service = build(APINAME, APIVERSION, developerKey = APIKEY)

#volumes source ('public'), search query ('androide')
searchrequest = service.search().list(q ='movie trailers', part ='id, snippet', maxResults = 25).execute()

searchcount = 0
print "-----------"
for search_result in searchrequest.get("items", []):
    searchcount +=1
    print searchcount
    print "Title:\t", search_result['snippet']['title']
    # print "Description:\t", search_result['snippet']['description']
    print "Uploaded by:\t", search_result['snippet']['channelTitle']
    print "Uploaded on:\t", search_result['snippet']['publishedAt']
    print "Video ID:\t", search_result['id']['videoId']
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Your description mentions `videoID`, but the code uses `videoId`.  (Granted it works for the first video, so maybe just a typo?)

Comment: Yup! You got it. Thanks! I realize I never really thanked you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use 'get' method for result.

```
result['id'].get('videoId')
```

there are in some element no this key.
if you use square parenteces, python throw exeption keyError, but if  you use 'get' method, python return None for element whitch have not key videoId

Answer (score 0):

Using `search()` method returns channels, playlists as well together with videos in search. That might be why your problem.

I use their interactive playgrounds to learn the structure of returned JSON, functions, etc. For your question, I suggest to visit https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list .

Make sure if a kind of an item is "youtube#video", then access `videoId` of that item.

Sample of code:

```py
...
for index in response["items"]: # response is a JSON file I have got from API
    tmp = {} # temporary dict to assert into my custom JSON
    if index["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
          tmp["videoID"] = index["id"]["videoId"]
...
```

This is a part of code from my personal project I am currently working on.

Answer (score -1):

Because some results to Key "ID", return:

```
{u'kind': u'youtube#playlist', u'playlistId': u'PLd0_QArxznVHnlvJp0ki5bpmBj4f64J7P'}
```

You can see, there is no key "videoId".