# KeyError for 'snippet' when using YouTube Data API RelatedToVideoID feature

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is my first ever question on Stack Overflow so please do tell me if anything remains unclear. :)

My issue is somewhat related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181888/keyerror-with-youtube-api-using-python). I am trying to use the YouTube Data API to sample videos for my thesis. I have done so successfully with the code below; however, when I change the criterion from a query (`q`) to `relatedToVideoId`, the unpacking section breaks for some reason.

It works outside of my loop, but not inside it (same story for the `.get()` suggestion from the other thread). Does anyone know why this might be and how I can solve it?

This is the (shortened) code I wrote which you can use to replicate the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Allocate credentials:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
api_key = "YOUR KEY SHOULD GO HERE"
# Session Build
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = api_key)

df_sample_v2  = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Video.ID", "Title", "Channel Name"])    
keywords       = ['Global Warming',
                  'Coronavirus'
                  ]
iter           = list(range(1, 150))
rand_selec_ids = ['H6u0VBqNBQ8',
                 'LEZCxxKp0hM'
                 ]
for i in iter:
        
      # Search Request
      request = youtube.search().list(
          part             = "snippet",
          #q               = keywords[4],
          relatedToVideoId = rand_selec_ids[1],
          type             = "video",
          maxResults       = 5000,
          videoCategoryId  = 28,
          order            = "relevance",
          eventType        = "completed",
          videoDuration    = "medium"
      ) 

      # Save Response
      response = request.execute()

      # Unpack Response
      rows = []

      for i in list(range(0, response['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage'])):

          rows.append([response['items'][i]['id']['videoId'],
                       response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'], # this is the problematic line
                       response['items'][i]['snippet']['channelTitle']]
                     )

      temp = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ["Video.ID", "Title", "Channel Name"])
      df_sample_v2 = df_sample_v2.append(temp)
      print(f'{len(df_sample_v2)} videos retrieved!')
```

The KeyError I get is at the second line of rows.append() where I try to access the snippet.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-c6c01139e372> in <module>
     45 
     46                 rows.append([response['items'][i]['id']['videoId'],
---> 47                              response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'],
     48                              response['items'][i]['snippet']['channelTitle']]
     49                            )

KeyError: 'snippet'
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: Sorry! I added the traceback to the question.

Comment: `'snippet'` does not exist after item: `response['item'][i]` Are you sure it is not supposed to be something like `response['snippet']`?

Comment: maybe first use `.key()` in `response['item'][i].key()` to see what keys you get - or check `if 'snippet' in response['item'][i]:` before you try to get it. Maybe server doesn't send this information.

Comment: shorter `for item in response['items']: row.append([item['id']['videoId'], ...])`

Comment: 'snippet' does exist within response['items'], I'm sure of that since I have managed to get the code running with a different criterion. And thanks for the suggestion on making the code more efficient, I have implemented it :). In the end the root cause of my issue lied in the below which stvar pointed out, thanks for your guys' suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that the property `resultsPerPage` [should not be used as an indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65104162/8327971) for the size of the array `items`.

The proper way to iterate the items obtained from the API is as follows (this is also the general *pythonic* way of doing such kind of iterations):

```py
for item in response['items']:
    rows.append([
        item['id']['videoId'],
        item['snippet']['title'],
        item['snippet']['channelTitle']
    ])
```

You may well add to your code the something like the *debugging* code below to convince yourself about the claim I made.

```py
print(f"resultsPerPage={response['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage']}")
print(f"len(items)={len(response['items'])}")
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much! This was indeed the root of the issue I was having :) Amazing work!